# AngularJS nested directive does not access sub directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS project needs a nested directive for **layer** and **item**.

```
<layer>
    <item>
    </item>
</layer>
```

And my JavaScript is like this.

```
angular.module('app', []);

var app = angular.module('app');

app.directive('layer', [
    function () {
        return {
            replace:true,
            transclude:true,
            template: "<div></div>",
            link:function(){

            }
        }
    }
]);

app.directive('item', [
    function () {
        return {                    
            require:"^layer",
            template: "<div></div>",
            link: function(){
                console.log("ok")
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

But the `console.log("ok")` does not populate in `item` directive.

Comment: can you give an example of expected output?

Comment: expected output is browser console writes "ok".

Comment: you used replace:true in 'layer' so it replaces the dom by <div> which does n't have anything to compile, so 'item' is never called.

Comment: I know `replace:true` changes own template with <div> but not inner directive. Does it wrong?

Comment: i would say, more precisely it repalces the "element" itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ng-transclude` directive in the template to indicate where the transcluded content will be contained. Without this, the content will be discarded which is why you're not seeing the `console.log` message. Here is a working example that shows how to use transclusion:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('layer', [
    function() {
      return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div>layer<div ng-transclude></div></div>",
        link: function() {
          console.log('layer');
        }
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('item', [
    function() {
      return {
        template: "<div>item</div>",
        link: function() {
          console.log("ok");
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <layer>
    <item></item>
  </layer>
</div>
```